# Calling method from a specific childViewControllers class

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Alright, hope I can explain this as clearly as possible.

I have a Parent ViewController which has a ContainerView, this will contain different viewControllers/Class. I'm changing the content of this container at runtime like this:

```
    let newController = (storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: classIdentifierFromStoryboard))! as UIViewController
    let oldController = childViewControllers.last! as UIViewController

    oldController.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
    addChildViewController(newController)
    newController.view.frame = oldController.view.frame

    transition(from: oldController, to: newController, duration: 0, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations:{ () -> Void in
        }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in

    })

    oldController.removeFromParentViewController()
    newController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

So for example, the current controller that shows on UI is `firstVC`, which kinda look like

```
class firstVC {
    func removeAnnotations() {
        //something that removes annotation from MapVC
     }
}
```

On a certain event on the parent controller, how can I access the instance of firstVC so that i'll be able to call removeAnnotations? As of the moment I am getting nil, using this on parent controller `firstVC.removeAnnotations`, assumably this calls another instance of the class. Any help would be great! Hope my explanation makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run down the child view controllers like this:

```
for case let vc as firstVC in self.childViewControllers {
    vc.removeAnnotations()
}
```

This will run down all the child view controllers that are of type firstVC and execute the removeAnnotations method

Answer (score 0):

in this code is child view controller ProfileViewController

in first create one object of child view controller like this

```
 var objectProfile:ProfileViewController!
```

then viewDidLoad method

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        objectProfile = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileViewController") as! ProfileViewController
        objectProfile.view.frame = CGRect(x:  -(self.view.frame.size.width - 40), y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 40, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
        self.view.addSubview(objectProfile.view)
        self.navigationController?.didMove(toParentViewController: objectProfile)

        objectProfile.view.isHidden = true

    }
```

then button click method code here

```
 @IBAction func btnProfilePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) { 

            self.objectProfile.view.frame = CGRect(x:  0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 40, height: self.view.frame.size.height)


        }

    }
```

then touchesBegan

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        objectProfile.view.isHidden = false

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {

            self.objectProfile.view.frame = CGRect(x:  -(self.view.frame.size.width - 40), y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 40, height: self.view.frame.size.height)


       }

    }
```

complete set this code out put is

[image]
[image]

Comment: This isn't answering the original question.  This shows how to add a child view controller but in the original question the transition between two child view controllers was already being done what was required was how to access the new child view controller after the transition.